# Beginner Q: Measuring current via USB charging cable

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, usb, current-measurement, multimeter

I was trying to use the multimeter to find out what current does my charging cable actually provides to the phone. How do I accomplish this without completely destroying my cable?

Right now I can measure the voltage (~ 5.15 to 5.2 V) and V~ (Ac voltage? which is around 10-11 ) but not able to figure out a proper way to find our current. Will be very grateful for any pointers.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it with a multimeter without dismantling the cable or building a breakout, but you can get a gizmo to measure it properly: http://www.dx.com/p/bstuo-mini-usb-current-voltage-meter-tester-voltmeter-black-440156

Comment: Either cut the cable, use a low current DC clamp meter, or google "keweisi usb tester".

Comment: I bought one of  those USB voltage and current measurement devices from amazon. They may be called USB power meters. If I find the exact unit I will post another comment, don't have it right now.

Comment: @Dampmaskin DC clamp meter also requires cutting the cable - only the positive or negative wire should go through clamp not both. And measuring 0.5A DC with a clamp meter would not be precise enough.

Comment: Yes it would require stripping some insulation, but not cutting wires. My cheapo UT210E can measure DC currents with a precision of only a few milliamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or another, you'll have to break into your cable.

USB cables are cheap.  Get a short one just for this purpose, especially if you want to do this more than once.  The best would be one of those USB "extension" cables with a type A plug on one end and a socket on the other.  These things are not good for the USB signal, so get the shortest one you can find.

Very carefully cut open the outer jacket of the cable.  That should expose four separate wires.  Finding which is which might be tricky.  Worst case, expose a little bit of the bare wire of each, then use a ohmmeter or continuity tester to see which is connected to which pins of the plug.  You can look up which plug pin is which conductor.

Cut the power wire and solder about 100 mΩ in line with it.  Bring out connections to both ends of the resistor.  Now fix the cable by using electrical tape or hot glue.

At this point, you have a regular USB extension cable with two wires coming out of it from the middle somewhere.  Insert the cable in-line with the device you want to test.  Connect a voltmeter to the two leads coming out of the test cable.  The voltage will be the power current times the resistance you added to the cable.  For example, if you added a 100 mΩ resistor, then the voltmeter will show 100 mV for every 1 A of current.